# RadGridView Dynamic columns adding

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to combine static and dynamic columns in my RadGridView.
The problem is that dynamic column represents object with different properties that should be displayed within one cell.

This is how I add columns:

```
InitializeComponent();

        // Get some mock data
        ICollection <EmployeeRecord> employeeRecords = GetDummyData();

        this.grid.ItemsSource = employeeRecords;

        //Add the known columns
        this.grid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn() 
        { 
            UniqueName = "EmployeeName"
            , DataMemberBinding = new Binding("EmployeeName")
        });

        this.grid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
        {
            UniqueName = "ID"
            , DataMemberBinding = new Binding("ID")
        });


        // Now add the dynamic number of columns

        // Determines the maximum number of months that any employee has worked.
        int maxNumberOfMonths = employeeRecords.Max((x) => x.Subjects.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumberOfMonths; i++)
        {
            this.grid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
            {
                UniqueName = "Subject " + (i + 1) ,
                DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Subjects[" + i + "]"),
                CellTemplate = this.Resources["SubjectTemplate"] as DataTemplate,
                DataType = typeof(Subject)
            });
        }
```

Data template for cell

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubjectTemplate" DataType="ticket212220CreateGridColumnsOnTheFly:Subject">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Subject"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Mark"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Mark}"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Model

```
 public class EmployeeRecord
{
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>();
    public IList<Subject> Subjects
    {
        get { return this.subjects; }
    }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get;set; }
}
```

Generating fake data

```
      static ICollection<EmployeeRecord> GetDummyData()
    {
        ICollection<EmployeeRecord> employeeRecords = new List<EmployeeRecord>();

        EmployeeRecord stevie = new EmployeeRecord() { EmployeeName = "Steven Gerrard", ID = 333 };
        stevie.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Math",
            Mark = 5
        });

        employeeRecords.Add(stevie);

        EmployeeRecord ryan = new EmployeeRecord() { EmployeeName = "Ryan Giggs", ID = 222 };
        ryan.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Math",
            Mark = 5
        });
        ryan.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Geograph",
            Mark = 3
        });
        employeeRecords.Add(ryan);

        EmployeeRecord john = new EmployeeRecord() { EmployeeName = "John Terry", ID = 111 };
        john.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Math",
            Mark = 5
        });
        john.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Geograph",
            Mark = 3
        });
        john.Subjects.Add(new Subject
        {
            Name = "Physics",
            Mark = 7
        });
        employeeRecords.Add(john);

        return employeeRecords;
    }
```

Any idea why Name and Mark are not displayed in cell?

Comment: Where is your GetDummyData() method? You seem to have forgotten to post it.

Comment: sorry.added GetDummyData method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of a cell is an `EmployeeRecord` object since you set the `ItemsSource` property to an `ICollection<EmployeeRecord>`.

If you want to display all subjects for an employee in a column, you could use an `ItemsControl` that binds to the `Subjects` collection of the `EmployeeRecord`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SubjectTemplate" DataType="ticket212220CreateGridColumnsOnTheFly:Subject">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0 3 0 0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Subject" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Mark" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Mark}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Not really what I need.The purpose is to display one subject per cell.That is why I try to bind to Subjects[i] instead of Subjects property

Comment: Well, what do you need? Also the answer to your original question of "any idea why Name and Mark are not displayed in cell" should be very clear.

Comment: similar scenario is here but instead of int I have object which I need to display in template
http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-columns-from-collection

Comment: Your question was why "Name and Mark are not displayed" and this is because the DataContext of the cell is an EmployeeRecord and this class has no Name and Mark properties. Please ask another question if you have another issue.

Comment: It is strange.As in example above we can see that  DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Subjects[" + i + "]") should take one Subject not whole EmployeeRecord.

Anyway thank you for help,mm8 ! Will continue investigation.

Comment: You are binding to Subjects[" + i + "] of the EmployeeRecord and there is no such property. Again: The DataContext of a cell is the corresponding EmployeeRecord in the ItemsSource collection of the DataGrid and nothing else. There is not much to investigate.

Comment: But you are right.For some reason DataContext in DataTemplate is EmployeeRecord instead of Subject as it expected to be.

Comment: Then your expectations are clearly wrong. The DataContext of a cell is *always* an object in the ItemsSource.